# Using KendoUI's .kendoMaskedTextBox, how would you mask specific characters?

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, masking

I can easily mask a text field input with KendoUI's `.kendoMaskedTextBox`:

```
$("#MainContent_txtMailingZip").kendoMaskedTextBox({
    mask: "L0L 0L0"
});
```

However, I would now only like to accept the letters M and L for the first character.

How would one accomplish this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added a regex validation to the field.  While it doesn't satisfy the keypress filter, it does the trick:

```
    <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="RegularExpressionValidator1" runat="server" CssClass="field-validation-error" ErrorMessage="<%#ResourceApplicantIntakeCustomerInformation.msgInvalidPostalCode%>" ControlToValidate="txtMailingZip" ForeColor="red" Enabled="true" 
        ValidationExpression="^[KLMNP][0-9][A-Z] ?[0-9][A-Z][0-9]$"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe that is possible, the following are the valid mask rules from the API documentation. http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/maskedtextbox#configuration-mask

> 0 - Digit. Accepts any digit between 0 and 9.
>
> 9 - Digit or space. Accepts any digit between 0 and 9, plus space.
>
> # - Digit or space. Like 9 rule, but allows also (+) and (-)
>   signs.
>
> L - Letter. Restricts input to letters a-z and A-Z. This rule is
>   equivalent to [a-zA-Z] in regular expressions.
>
> ? - Letter or space. Restricts input to letters a-z and A-Z. This rule
>   is equivalent to [a-zA-Z] in regular expressions.
>
> & - Character. Accepts any character. The rule is equivalent to \S in
>   regular expressions.
>
> C - Character or space. Accepts any character. The rule is equivalent
>   to . in regular expressions.
>
> A - Alphanumeric. Accepts letters and digits only.
>
> a - Alphanumeric or space. Accepts letters, digits and space only.
>
> . - Decimal placeholder. The decimal separator will be get from the
>   current culture used by Kendo.
>
> , - Thousands placeholder. The display character will be get from the
>   current culture used by Kendo.
>
> $ - Currency symbol. The display character will be get from the
>   current culture used by Kendo.

Comment: You could probably handle the the keyup or change events and prevent the input as well.

// not enough rep to comment on your answer yet...

Answer (score 0):

It's what you want:

```
$("#MainContent_txtMailingZip").kendoMaskedTextBox({
    mask: "^0L 0L0",
    rules: { "^": /[ML]/ }
});
```